# Extract part of string using grep

Tags: sed, awk, grep, perl

I have 3 files in a directory

```
MYO144064T
MYO144064TA
MYO144064TX
```

Where the digits and 11th character will change.
In my csh script, I want to extract the letters 'A' and 'X' probably using grep

The variable $study equals MYO144064

What I have managed so far is very cumbersome

```
ls | grep $study | cut -c 11 | sed 's/\///'
```

Which gives me

```
A
X
```

How can I do this with minimal processes and without the additional blank line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls | grep -oP "(?<=$study.)[A-Z]$"
```

will return any uppercase letter that is preceded by the contents of `$study` plus one arbitrary character (the `T` in your example) and followed by the end of the line.

<sub>The `-P` option (Perl regular expressions) is needed to be able to use the positive lookbehind expression `(?<=...)`, but might not be available on every system and platform.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep $study | grep -o "[AX]$"
```

returns only the result of 'A' or 'X' as the last character

Comment: The 11th character will change, it may be A or X but could easily be M, Y, O or T

Comment: then ".$" will always get you the last character

Answer (score 0):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -nle 'print chop if length == 11' file
A
X
```

Or if you can use `bash`:

```
while read var
do
    [ ${#var} -eq 11 ] && echo ${var:(-1)}
done < file
```